# what is - gets is a directory - error message

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm getting this odd error...

```
/Users/gideon/Documents/ca_ruby/rubytactoe/lib/player.rb:13:in `gets': Is a directory - spec (Errno::EISDIR)
```

player_spec.rb:

```
    require_relative '../spec_helper'

# the universe is vast and infinite...it contains a game.... but no players
describe "tic tac toe game" do
  context "the player class" do
    it "must have a human player X"do
      player = Player.new("X")
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("human move")
      # player.stub(:gets).and_return("")
      player.move_human("X")
    end
    it "must have a computer player O" do
      player = Player.new("O")
      STDOUT.should_receive(:puts).with("computer move") #what I expect to get back
      player.stub(:gets).and_return("") #what I am sending
      player.move_computer("O") #the actual call
    end
  end
end
```

player.rb

```
    # require_relative 'drawgrid'

class Player

  attr_reader :boardpiece # i exist so game can read me

  def initialize(letter)
    @boardpiece = letter
  end

  def move_human(game)
    puts "human move..."
    @move = gets.chomp
  end

  def move_computer(game)
    puts "computer move..."
    # all possible third moves as 'O' (computer)
    @human_winmoves = {
        :wm01 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm02 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm03 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm04 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm05 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm06 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm07 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
        :wm08 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"X", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
        #check those corners
        :wm09 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm10 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm11 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm12 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm13 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
        :wm14 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>"X"},
        :wm15 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
        :wm16 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        #check opposites
        :wm17 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm18 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"X", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"X", :c3=>" "},
        :wm19 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
        :wm20 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm21 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"X", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"X", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm22 => {:a1=>"X", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
        :wm23 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"X"},
        :wm24 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"X", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"X", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}
    }

    @ai_winmoves = {
        :wm01 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm02 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm03 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm04 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm05 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm06 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm07 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "},
        :wm08 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>"O", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
        #check those corners
        :wm09 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm10 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm11 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm12 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm13 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
        :wm14 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>"O"},
        :wm15 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "},
        :wm16 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        #check opposites
        :wm17 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm18 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>"O", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>"O", :c3=>" "},
        :wm19 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
        :wm20 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm21 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>"O", :b2=>" ", :b3=>"O", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "},
        :wm22 => {:a1=>"O", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>" ", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
        :wm23 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>" ", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>"O"},
        :wm24 => {:a1=>" ", :a2=>" ", :a3=>"O", :b1=>" ", :b2=>" ", :b3=>" ", :c1=>"O", :c2=>" ", :c3=>" "}
    }
    # match current answers located in @thegrid with possible @anskey array, iterate for each item
    @anskey={
        :wm01=>"c3",:wm02=>"c2",:wm03=>"c1",:wm04=>"b3",:wm05=>"b1",:wm06=>"a3",:wm07=>"a2",:wm08=>"a1",
        :wm09=>"a3",:wm10=>"c1",:wm11=>"a1",:wm12=>"c3",:wm13=>"c3",:wm14=>"c1",:wm15=>"c3",:wm16=>"a1",
        :wm17=>"b1",:wm18=>"b2",:wm19=>"b3",:wm20=>"a2",:wm21=>"b2",:wm22=>"b2",:wm23=>"c2",:wm24=>"b2"
    }
    #
    # scan board for available move locations
    # select all values where value is O for thegrid and copy those into keys_with_o
    # compare result to ai_winmoves
    # keys_with_o = $thegrid.select{ |k, v| v == "O" }.keys
    # matching_moves = @ai_winmoves.select{ |k, v| v.select{ |k, v| v == "O" }.keys == keys_with_o }
    # puts "matching_moves: "
    # puts matching_moves

    # select all values where value is X for thegrid and copy those into keys_with_x
    keys_with_x = $thegrid.select{ |k, v| v == "X" }.keys
    block_moves = @ai_winmoves.select{ |k, v| v == "X" }.keys

    #DEBUG puts "keys_with_x: "
    #DEBUG puts keys_with_x.to_s

    # human_keys = v.select{ |k, v| v == "X"}.keys
    @intersection = block_moves & keys_with_x

    @thing = [] # initialize thing array

    @human_winmoves.each do |k,v| # for test - go threw each win moves.
      #get common elements between two arrays..recall from above that v contains a hash
      human_keys = v.select{ |k, v| v == "X"}.keys
      @intersection = human_keys & keys_with_x
      if $thegrid[:b2] == " "   #AND center spot is empty
        ai_spot = "b2"
        puts "take center "+ai_spot
        @move = ai_spot.to_sym  #must return this answer as a symbol
        return @move
      elsif @intersection.length >= 2
        #DEBUG puts "where does a intersect b"
        #DEBUG puts @intersection.to_s 
        #DEBUG puts "answer key:"
        #DEBUG puts k
        @thing << k # adds per iteration
        #DEBUG puts "@thing array"
        #DEBUG puts @thing.to_s # for test - find each intersection
        #DEBUG puts "@thing array first key"
        #DEBUG puts @thing.last.to_s
        #DEBUG puts "value"
        #DEBUG puts @anskey[@thing.last]
        #DEBUG puts "symbol?"
        answer = @anskey[@thing.last].to_sym
        #DEBUG puts answer.is_a?(Symbol)
        @move = answer # for test - at last intersection value found...return it as move value 
      end
    end # END @human_winmoves.each do |k,v|
    return @move # had this guy in the wrong place
  end
end
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you call `gets.chomp` you're actually referring to [`Kernel#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-gets), which expects a file to read from.  If you are passing command line arguments, they'll be interpreted as these input files `Kernel#gets` expects.  If one of the args is a directory path, then you'll get the error you mentioned.

You want to use [`IO#gets`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-i-gets) instead. This will work as expected:

```
def move_human(game)
  puts "human move..."
  @move = $stdin.gets.chomp
end
```

Comment: We encountered this problem recently when using RSpec 3 and `gets` together. Unsure why some students hit the problem and not others, but the `STDIN.gets.chomp` fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

**You are probably giving a directory name as command line argument.**

Kernel#gets reads from files given as command line arguments.
You are probably giving a directory name instead of a file name at the command line.

If there's no argument at the command line, it reads from STDIN.