# Issue with Rspec Test for a Ruby Script that takes user input for Hash elements

Tags: unit-testing, hash, user-input, rspec2, ruby-1.9.3

I have a [ruby script](https://github.com/boddhisattva/book/blob/master/book.rb) that takes the prices of the books from the user at run time. I'm new to writing RSpec tests for Ruby scripts. I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p327 and rspec 2.11.0. You can **clone** my project from **Github** [this link](https://github.com/boddhisattva/book).

My Rspec Test is intended to test if the newly instantiated object belongs to a specific class.

My test passes successfully if I comment line number 32 in the [ruby script](https://github.com/boddhisattva/book/blob/master/book.rb) .

Somehow when I uncomment that line, I'm getting the error below that is to do with user input. I'm not even testing this as part of my [spec file](https://github.com/boddhisattva/book/blob/master/spec/book_spec.rb), but still I'm landing up with this error. I don't know exactly why and how could I work my way around this issue.

```
The Last Samurai: /home/mohnish/xxx/yyy/sample_pocs/book/book.rb:11:in `gets': Is a directory - spec (Errno::EISDIR)
    from /home/mohnish/xxx/yyy/sample_pocs/book/book.rb:11:in `gets'
    from /home/mohnish/xxx/yyy/sample_pocs/book/book.rb:11:in `block in get_prices'
from /home/mohnish/xxx/yyy/sample_pocs/book/book.rb:9:in `each'
    from /home/mohnish/xxx/yyy/sample_pocs/book/book.rb:9:in `inject'
    from /home/mohnish/xxx/yyy/sample_pocs/book/book.rb:9:in `get_prices'
from /home/mohnish/xxx/yyy/sample_pocs/book/book.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/mohnish/xxx/yyy/sample_pocs/book/spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `require_relative'
    from /home/mohnish/xxx/yyy/sample_pocs/book/spec/spec_helper.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from /home/mohnish/xxx/yyy/sample_pocs/book/spec/book_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@book_set/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@book_set/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@book_set/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `map'
from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@book_set/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:780:in `load_spec_files'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@book_set/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@book_set/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
from /home/mohnish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@book_set/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:8:in `block in autorun'
```

I also want to test for the user input for this example. It would be great if you could throw some light on how could I got about the same as well. I found some places where I can get started with testing user input like [eg 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258630/how-do-i-write-an-rspec-test-for-a-ruby-method-that-contains-gets-chomp) and [eg 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609872/rspec-commandline-variable-input), but I'm mainly looking how to test user input for a number of elements that belong to a hash

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
STDIN.gets.chomp
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12677677/131226).

The best way to test this is to mock `IO#gets` with an object and method that returns a canned response. An RSpec mock would look something like:

```
STDIN.should_receive(:gets).and_return("A Book Title")
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6335974/131226) for a couple more examples. Set these up in the appropriate `before :each` blocks and they will intercept the call to `gets` in your test.

Comment: Thanks Sean. That fixed the error. I probably should have refined my search to "`gets': Is a directory - spec". I'm Learning the way.. :). Any inputs on how could I write a spec for user input of Hash elements ?

Comment: The user is inputing some string that gets converted to a Hash, or the method is expecting an actual Hash?

Comment: The user input is a string and each such string is stored as a value for each key element in the Hash.

Comment: I'm accepting your answer as it mainly did solve the gets error for me. Thank you.